# How do you calculate or predict the probability of a hotel booking cancellation (Excel)?

Tags: probability, excel

based on past hotel booking transactions, what will be a good and simple way to calculate and predict the probability of cancellation of a hotel booking transaction using excel?

I was thinking of using these dataset features such as booking lead time, number of nights stayed, the number of pax(parents/children), gender, when it was booked.... etc

Comment: There's not really anything in this question to distinguish it from any generic classification problem, so it would appear that you have the enormous range of options available in [tag:machine-learning] available for your use. If you're asking specifically *how to use Excel*, then that is not an on-topic question here; please review the [help] for information about how to use this website.

Comment: You don't. Or, at least, I wouldn't. That is, if I had to do something like this I would use a statistical package. Personally, I'd use SAS but other packages would be fine (R, Python, Matlab....) .  Excel is not really designed for complicated statistics. 

As @Sycorax pointed out, there's a huge array of possible methods. Figuring out which would be best in which situation isn't simple. 

If this is for an actual business, I'd suggest hiring a consultant.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression is the goto first try to predict whether something does happen or does not happen from a multivariate sample. It is a generalized form of linear regression that will predict values between $0$ and $1$ that can be interpreted as probabilities between 0% and 100%.

I have never unsed Excel for logistic regression but there is a huge number of introductory texts and videos to be found using the search terms "Excel logistic regression".

Should you find that logistic regression does not quite fit the way people cancel their hotel bookings have a look at decision trees, though my first search results seem to show only hand-drawn, not automatic decisions trees. I have found these links without confirming them, though:

```
www.stricklensolutions.com/excel-add-ins/solutiontree/solutiontree-decision-trees-in-excel.php
www.treeplan.com
go.palisade.com/DTSDownload.html
```

It can also be done with free software outside of Excel.